# AWS CodeBuild: Create connection to Bitbucket repository that I have access to but do not own it

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codestar

I am setting up a CodeBuild project where the source provider is Bitbucket. In order to do so I have to create a Codestar-connection to Bitbucket repository. I can only do so with repositories that I own. It does not list the repositories where I even have admin privileges that are owned by someone else.

There's nothing much I can show you, but I'm referring to this:

[image]

Has anyone found a work around for this? I have **scraped** through almost everything that is there on the internet but couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: We have posted a workaround in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72494699/6783241](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72494699/6783241)

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of how Bitbucket Apps work. Customers will only be able to see repositories owned by the Bitbucket account used to create the connection.

A workaround is to create a Team from the bitbucket account and from CodeBuild you can see all the repository belonging to team.