# AWS Code PipeLine not getting all repository of BitBucket account

Tags: bitbucket, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS CodeBuild and CodePipeline service to implement CI/CD in my project.

AWS CodeBuild using Bitbucket I am getting all repository of my Bitbucket account.

While Creating CodePipeLine and connect with my BitBucket, I can't get all repository of my BitBucket account.

- I have admin access to BitBucket.
- AWS CodeStar injected successfully in Bitbucket

So is there any extra setting need in the BitBucket account for implement AWS Codepipeline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CodePipeline uses a Bitbucket App installed on your Bitbucket account to access repositories. Currently Bitbucket only allows Apps to access repositories on the same account that the App was installed on.[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/connections-bitbucket.html) I’ve passed this feedback onto the CodePipeline team who is partnering with Atlassian on this integration.

For now you can try this workaround:

1. Select the connection
2. Type the name of the Repo as `<account>/<repository-name>` in the "Repository name" field
3. Select the branch

CodePipeline connection should be able to retrieve the repo when you run the pipeline.

**References**

1: [Bitbucket connections only provide access to repositories owned by the Bitbucket account that was used to create the connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/connections-bitbucket.html).

Comment: it's not working. can you explain what is Account Name? I have been shared with a workspace named "XYZ LLC". I have the admin access on a repo inside this workspace. but I am not able to access this repo in the code pipeline.

Comment: I had the same problem. After spending few hours, I got to know that. The bitbucket repository should belong to your own workspace. If you create a workspace in bitbucket then all the created repositories inside that workspace is visible in codepipeline, repositories belonging to other workspaces which isn't created by you is not displayed even if you have admin privileges for that repository. This is a dumb feature which Atlassian-AWS should change.

Comment: accountname/repo_name  can someone explain what it is?

Comment: @surajshetty's solution worked for me. I've imported all the shared repositories in my root workspace in bitbucket. After that all the imported repos are visible in AWS CodePipeline

Comment: The only way to grant the "App" access to a shared workspace is with Admin privileges.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2022 and honestly makes no sense from a devops workflow POV. What happens if we have an organization and the repos are managed in that org's workspace? The only solution is that we make our own workspace but that's also counter intuitive. There should be a way to delegate access to certain repos in a workspace to accounts so they can use them as source in codepipeline.

Comment: 2023 Doesn't work after entering BS/repo. The whole source in the pipeline is counter intuitive since I already defined it in the CodeBuild. All I want to do is execute the build and the deploy. Then create a bitbucket webhook to trigger pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Bitbucket only allows Apps to access repositories on the same account.

You can create a webhook from Bitbucket to GitHub and connect the correct Github repo to CodePipeline.

[https://poeditor.com/blog/webhooks-solution-automate-sync-poeditor-github-bitbucket-repos/#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20webhook%20to,URL%20in%20the%20empty%20field.](https://poeditor.com/blog/webhooks-solution-automate-sync-poeditor-github-bitbucket-repos/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20a%20webhook%20to,URL%20in%20the%20empty%20field.)

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get acces to the repositories in another workspace by giving, to our bitbucket service account, workspace administration rights.
We added it to a group that has the right to
[Permission needed for account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7M4v.png)

For sure, you need a bitbucket administrator doing that for you.

Having done that, we can create a codestart connexion that access the repository in another workspace.

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is what worked for me, I had to add 2 things.

The first thing is that when the repository belongs to a workspace, you should not put what it says about:

owner/repository name.

you should put:

workspace name/repository name.

And you say, where do I get the name of the workspace?
It's in the url when you clone the repository.
Here is an example:

"git clone https://ExampleName@bitbucket.org/workspace-name/repository-name.git"

the second thing is that you probably still have an error in the pipeline that says you don't have permissions, so looking for the answer, in this forum they say that you should add the following permissions to the role of your bitbucket connection. The reason is because there are some problems when aws changed the version of this service. Here is the article:

https://haydnjmorris.medium.com/solving-permissions-error-with-aws-codepipeline-c93cfc000285

and here is what you should add to the role.

```
{
  "Action": [
    "codestar-connections:UseConnection".
],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Effect": "Allow"
},
{
  "Action": [
    "appconfig:StartDeployment",
    "appconfig:GetDeployment",
    "appconfig:StopDeployment"
],
  "Resource": "*",
  "effect": "Allow"
},
{
  "Action": [
    "codecommit:GetRepository".
],
  "resource": "*",
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

and you're done!
up and running!
hope this helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).