# AWS Code Pipeline How to access the repositories in other organizations (I have the admin access to the repository)

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codepipeline

To provide a Bitbucket source to my AWS Code Pipeline I have tried the answer in this link [Code Pipleline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184789/aws-code-pipeline-not-getting-all-repository-of-bitbucket-account)
but I am not able to access the repository which is not directly in my account but instead, it has been shared with me with admin rights. I am able to access only the repositories which are under my account. But how do I access the repositories which are shared with me?

In the above link, there is an answer upvoted but I am not able find out the Account Name of the organization who has shared this repository with me. Do I need to ask the account name of the organization manually or is there a way to find it out.
And by the way I am not able to understand this behavior as well. I mean the process should be more smooth and straight forward. AWS never mentioned this scenario in their documentation as well for how to address this problem. There's not much related to it could be found on SO as well.
Any help please.